# Changing the UIKeyboard background color get app rejected

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uikeyboard

I have this piece of code in my app to change the background color of the keyboard by removing the backdropView and setting the keyboard.backgroundColor...

Will this get my app rejected from the app store. I'd love to know a better way of doing it but so far no luck...and I don't want to use the light or dark appearance options. Thanks!

```
for (UIWindow* window in [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows) {
        for (UIView *possibleKeyboard in window.subviews) {
            if ([[possibleKeyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIPeripheralHostView"]) {

                keyboard = possibleKeyboard;

                for (UIView *view in keyboard.subviews) {
                    if([[view description ] hasPrefix:@"<UIKBInputBackdropView"]) {
                        view.hidden=YES;
                    }
                }
                keyboard.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueGrayColor];
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I guess, you cant change keyboard style with code.

Comment: Did it get rejected? I'm currently working on something and would like to know if setting the UIKBInputBackdropView.layer.opacity to 0 is safe for the store?

Comment: I didn't ever submit that way.